# how to catch all occurrences

Tags: php, regex

I have list of `<key, value>` pairs formatted as this string:

Akey=valueBAkey=valueB...

So for example the string `Ak1=v1BAk2=v2BAk3=v3B` gives the following three pairs:

```
k1 = v1
k2 = v2
k3 = v3
```

I am trying to subtract all of the `<key, value>` pairs using a regular expression in PHP.

The regular expression I got so far is as following:

```
.*A(.+)=(.+)B.*
```

But this only catches the last pair, being `k3=v3`.

How do I catch all occurrences?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you're not getting this?

```
name: k1=v1BAk2=v2BAk3
 key: v3
```

If you are, your first `.+` is matching the `B` and everything following it up until the last `=`.

I recommend using the non-greedy modifier `?`:

```
/.*A(.+?)=(.+?)B.*/
```

Also make sure that you're using `preg_match_all`, not `preg_match`. It's PHP's equivalent of giving the regex engine the `/g` flag to allow more than a single match.

Comment: @rockerest: That's not entirely helpful feedback. What did you learn from it? What precisely does "doesn't work" mean here? Can you show us a [live testcase](http://codepad.org) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: It returns the last key and value as individual array values, but none of the rest.  Also, although I'm not positive, I don't think you can double the modifiers by putting a + and then a ? since the + means "at LEAST one" and then the ? means "zero OR one", those two conflict.  I'm not 100% on that though.  In any case, plugging this regex into a test (like [this tester](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php)) with the OP's data returns the same results he started with.

Comment: @rockerest: No, `?` here _modifies_ the `+` to make it "at least one, but still as few as possible to get an overall match."

Comment: ah, alright.  That makes sense.  Some of the finer points of regex escape me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different regex like this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/A([^=]+)=([^B]+)B/', 'Ak1=v1BAk2=v2BAk3=v3B', $m) > 0) {
   var_dump($m[1]); // prints keys
   var_dump($m[2]); // prints values

}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "k1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "k2"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "k3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "v1"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "v2"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "v3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non-greedy mode: `A(.+?)=(.+?)B`

`.+?` and `.*?` are used to catch all the characters until the next character is found.

Answer (score 0):

## Another Update

this regex: `/A(k\d+=(v\d+))B/` will give you an array of the `k=v` matches and an array of just the values.

Try it on [this regex tester](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php).  Looks like it's giving you the results you would want.  This assumes that "k", "v", "A", and "B" are static, but you should be able to change it to accept dynamic values.

(in fact, here's the one that would take any value: `/A(.*?=(.*?))B/`)

## update

Actually, I just noticed you're using PHP.

Just use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get an array of all of the occurrences in the string.

### original

Probably by using the global operator `//g`

That matches all occurrences instead of just the last (or first).

Comment: No, he has a bug in his expression. (Though, yes, he should be using `preg_match_*all*` if he's not already.)

Comment: @Tomalak You're probably right.  I haven't really dissected the expression itself, so that's probably where the issue lies anyway.